# How to make a frame with at most a certain width and always the shorter as possible?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to build a component which receives a name and displays it inside of a frame. I want this frame to have the smallest width as possible respecting the paddings and avoiding breaking the line. The limit for the width is 90: after that, the line of text should be broken. I've tried to use the `maxWidth` attribute of the `frame` modifier, but my frame gets a fixed 90 value as width. Here is a code snippet of the component:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var name: String

    var body: some View {
        Text(name)
            .font(.system(size: 12))
            .background(Color.red)
            .padding(.horizontal, 7)
            .padding(.vertical, 5)
            .background(Color.yellow)
            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 90)
            .background(Color.green)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView(name: "This is a very long name")
                .previewDisplayName("Long name")
            ContentView(name: "Hi")
                .previewDisplayName("Short name")
        }
        .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
    }
}
```

[The preview looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXMw1.png)

I've also tried to use the `minWidth` and `idealWidth` attributes, but the result is always the same. How can I make the width take 90 as a limit instead of a fixed value?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure if this is what you want, but if you move the frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: 90) modifier to make it the last one than all views early in the modifier chain will have a size that is less than or equal to the maxWidth. Any modifier later in the chain than the frame modifier will not vary in size.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually `fixedSize` by one axis should work, but for some reason it is not, so proposed below only *run-time* solution (not for static Preview), ie. calculated limit manually and apply on next refresh (to avoid cycling).

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoTightingText: View {
    var name: String
    @State private var maxWidth: CGFloat = 90
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(name)
                .font(.system(size: 12))
                .background(Color.red)
                .padding(.horizontal, 7)
                .padding(.vertical, 5)
                .background(Color.yellow)
                .background(GeometryReader {gp -> Color in
                        DispatchQueue.main.async {
                            // update on next cycle with calculated width !!!
                            self.maxWidth = min(gp.size.width, 90)
                        }
                        return Color.clear
                    })
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: maxWidth)
        .background(Color.green)
//      .fixedSize(horizontal: true, vertical: false) // this must be work, but don't
    }
}
```